# Error expected struct `AccountId32`, found associated type when saving an AccountId who

Tags: rust

I have a data structure as follows

```
// definition for account id is 
// pub type AccountId = <<Signature as Verify>::Signer as IdentifyAccount>::AccountId;

use primitives::{AccountId, Balance, Price};

#[derive(PartialEq, Eq, Clone, Encode, Decode, RuntimeDebug, TypeInfo)]
#[scale_info(skip_type_params(T))]
pub struct Alpha{
    pub alpha: AccountId,
    pub cost: Price,
}

#[derive(PartialEq, Eq, Clone, Encode, Decode, RuntimeDebug, TypeInfo, Default)]
#[scale_info(skip_type_params(T))]
pub struct Wallet{
    pub avg: Price,
    pub alphas: Vec<Alpha>,
}
```

and Storage Declaration

```
#[pallet::storage]
    #[pallet::getter(fn get_big_wallet)]
    pub type BigWallet<T: Config> = StorageDoubleMap<
        _,
        Blake2_128Concat,
        CurrencyId,
        Blake2_128Concat,
        RoundNumber,
        Wallet,
        OptionQuery,
    >;
```

When I tried to save data um getting the following error

```
let who = ensure_signed(origin)?; // this works
let mut record= Self::get_big_wallet(asset_id, round).unwrap_or_default(); // this works


let mut members= record.alpha;
let sub_len = members.len() as u128;

            let data= Alpha{
                alpa: who.clone(),
                price,
            };


Error: alpa: who.clone(),
    |                            ^^^^^^^^^^^ expected struct `AccountId32`, found associated type
```

How to fix this error above? How to save an account ( who ) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the `AccountId` type from `sp_primitives`.
What you rather want to do is to use the `AccountId` from your pallet configuration which is accessible as `T::AccountId` or something like `<T as frame_system::Config>` depending on your pallet config.

```rust
use primitives::{Balance, Price};

type AccountIdOf<T> = <T as frame_system::Config>::AccountId;

#[derive(PartialEq, Eq, Clone, Encode, Decode, RuntimeDebug, TypeInfo)]
pub struct Alpha<AccountId>{
    pub alpha: AccountId,
    pub cost: Price,
}

#[derive(PartialEq, Eq, Clone, Encode, Decode, RuntimeDebug, TypeInfo, Default)]
pub struct Wallet<AccountId>{
    pub avg: Price,
    pub alphas: Vec<Alpha<AccountId>>,
}

// Use the wallet as:
Wallet<AccountIdOf<T>>
```

You can also pass in `T::AccountId` as generic type instead of the complete Config.